# Inconveniente para visualizar información en un archivo generado en python

Tags: python

Estoy usando el siguiente código para hacer un archivo de texto, para poder leer y escribir información. El código fue hecho para hacerlo con archivos binarios (están comentadas estas lineas y funciona), pero yo lo modifique para hacerlo con txt. Cuando corro el código con la modificación funciona (no da errores) pero al abrir el archivo sale lo siguiente:

> self.personas=[<**main**.Persona object at 0x0000026C3F19D828>].

No se si algo va mal. Se explica el código (lo saque de ahí)(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3qvf1fTCsU)

```
from io import open
import pickle

class Persona:
    def __init__(self,nombre,genero,edad):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.genero=genero
        self.edad=edad
        print("Se ha creado una persona nueva con el nombre  de",self.nombre)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.nombre,self.genero,self.edad)

class ListaPersonas:
    personas=[]

    def __init__(self):
        #listaDePersonas=open("ficheroexterno","ab+")
        listaDePersonas=open("ficheroexterno.txt","a")
        listaDePersonas.seek(0)

        try:
            #self.personas=pickle.load(listaDePersonas)
            self.personas=listaDePersonas.read()
            print("Se cargaron {} personas del  fichero externo".format(len(self.personas)))

        except:
            print("El fichero esta vacio")

        finally:
            listaDePersonas.close()
            #del(listaDePersonas)


    def agregarPersona(self,p):
        self.personas.append(p)
        self.guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno()


    def mostrarPersonas(self):
        for p in self.personas:
            print(p)

    def guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno(self):
        #listaDePersonas=open("ficheroexterno","wb")
        listaDePersonas=open("ficheroexterno.txt","w")
        #pickle.dump(self.personas,listaDePersonas)
        listaDePersonas.write('self.personas=%s'%self.personas)
        listaDePersonas.close()
        #del(listaDePersonas)

    def mostrarInfoFicheroExterno(self):
        print("La informacipn del fichero externo es la siguiente")
        for p in self.personas:
            print(p)

miLista=ListaPersonas()
persona=Persona("Sandra","Femeino","29")
miLista.agregarPersona(persona)
miLista.mostrarInfoFicheroExterno()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el siguiente.

Cuando intentas escribir en el fichero, en la línea que pone:

```
    listaDePersonas.write('self.personas=%s'%self.personas)
```

has usado la cadena de formato `%s` que intentará volcar como string el valor de `self.personas`, pero `self.personas` es una lista. Python tiene ya predefinido cómo volcar una lista como cadena, y para ello hace lo siguiente:

- Genera el carácter `'['`
- Cada uno de los elementos de la lista se convierte a cadena haciendo `repr(elemento)`
- Se concatenan todos, separándolos por comas
- Se genera el carácter `']'`.

En definitiva, se hace algo equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
convertido = '[' + ', '.join(repr(e) for e in lista) + ']'
```

Así que en tu caso, se está haciendo `repr()` de cada persona en la lista. Esta función llama al método `__repr__()` de la persona, y si éste no existe, entonces genera una representación por defecto que es del estilo `<Clase object at 0xXXXX>`, informándote de que se trata de un objeto de esa clase y de la dirección de memoria en que está almacenado.

Tú habías programado un método `__str__()` para convertir una persona en cadena, pero ese método se llama si haces `str(persona)` y no si haces `repr(persona)`.

Tienes dos soluciones:

- Implementar un método `__repr__()` (simplemente puede consistir en `return str(self)`)
- Implementar tu propio bucle para generar la representación en cadena de la lista:

  ```
  listaDePersonas.write('self.personas=[%s]' % ', '.join(str(p) for p in self.personas))
  ```

Por cierto que la sintaxis con `%` empieza ya a verse como obsoleta (aunque aún está soportada) y se aconseja usar `str.format()`, o si estás en Python 3.6+ las nuevas f-strings.